# How to filter data in get_context_data

Tags: django

I have 2 models ...

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    po_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=get_po_number)
    po_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_number = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PurchaseOrderItem(models.Model):
    po_number_fk = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

One for purchase orders(PurchaseOrder), and one for items within a specific purchase order(PurchaseOrderItem)

I'm trying to access the data for both models in one TemplateView...

```
class PurchaseOrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'financial/purchase_orders/purchase_order_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PurchaseOrderDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['purchase_order'] = PurchaseOrder.objects.get()
        context['item'] = PurchaseOrderItem.objects.filter()
        return context
```

but I'm unsure of how to filter the purchase_order.pk based on the pk passed through the URL, and I'm unsure how to filter the items.po_number_fk based on the purchase_order.pk. I know I need to put the login in my PurchaseOrder.objects.get() and PurchaseOrderItem.objects.filter() but not sure what the logic needs to be

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to your PurchaseOrder model, otherwise you can't filter on user and any logged-in user can see any other user's orders. Also if I were you I would rename `po_number_fk` to `order` or `purchase_order`, so that it was more obvious.

You can refer to `pk` field via `self.kwargs['pk']` and filter both models (if you do everything mentioned above) this way:

```
class PurchaseOrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'financial/purchase_orders/purchase_order_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PurchaseOrderDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk, user = self.kwargs['pk'], self.request.user
        context['purchase_order'] = PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=pk, user=user)
        context['item'] = PurchaseOrderItem.objects.filter(order=pk)
        return context
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Also I actually did have user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) along with a lot of other fields but I left those out of my earlier post. Thanks for your help and I'll take your suggestion of renaming po_number_fk

Comment: how can you apply the django-filter package to the context dictionary? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973937/django-filter-queryset-show-variables-on-template